# ConnectNamedPipe() function triggers "Debug Error! abort()" when called from within a method of a Functor that's passed as an argument to a new Thread

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17, named-pipes, abort

**Error**

Executing the below in Visual Studio triggers "*Debug Error! abort() has been called*":

```
if(m_handle==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return(false); // no return here, therefore m_handle is valid (?)
if(!m_connected){ // some bool indicating a connection doesn't already exist

    if(ConnectNamedPipe(m_handle,NULL)==0){ // --- Abort() message triggered here ----
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Context**

The above code is part of a `connectClient()` method of a `PipeFunctor` class that overloads the function call operator `()`; and within that overloaded function is a call to `connectClient()`:

```
void PipeFunctor::operator()() {
    connectClient(); // PipeFunctor::connectClient() called here
    // ... 
}
```

The `connectClient()` method is *indirectly* called via the functor passed to thread, i.e.:

```
PipeFunctor pipeF();
// ...
std::thread (std::ref(pipeF));
```

**Hypothesis**

When `connectClient()` is *directly* called (as shown below), the same offending `ConnectNamedPipe()` statement executes **without** a Debug *abort()* error:

```
PipeFunctor pipeF();
// ...
pipeF.connectClient();
```

This leads me to believe that it is the thread execution statement, `std::thread (std::ref(pipeF));`, that causes the issue downstream.

**1.** Is there a way I can begin a new thread by passing it a functor object that contains, and subsequently calls, the `ConnectNamedPipe()` function, without producing this debug *abort()* error?

**2.** What's the best way to resolve this issue?

All suggestions appreciated.

Thanks!

***Additional Info***:

The `m_handle` variable is (seemingly successfully) created from within the `connectClient()` (as shown below) method *prior* to the offending function `ConnectNamedPipe()` being called:

```
if(!pipename || *pipename==0) return(false); // no return here. pipeName is a correctly initialized LPTSTR variable

   m_handle = CreateNamedPipe(pipename,PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
                            PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,
                            PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,256*1024,256*1024,5000,NULL);

   if(m_handle==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){ // produces if(false)
      wprintf(L"Creating pipe '%s' failed\n",pipename);
      return(false);
   }
```

Comment: My crystal ball thinks that you're using two different objects and not initializing `m_handle` to `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.

Comment: Win32 APIs don't use `abort()`. Something else is going on.

Comment: @molbdnilo I checked the m_handle that is created, and it appears to point to the exact same location as the one that is used. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Agreed. I did some further investigations and believe it has to do with calling that ConnectNamedPipe() function from a functor object that is passed to a new thread. Please see my updated post for explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PipeFunctor pipeF();` is a **function declaration** (a function named `pipeF` taking no arguments and returning a `PipeFunctor`). It is not a **variable declaration**, like you probably intended. `PipeFunctor pipeF;` is a variable declaration, as is `PipeFunctor pipeF{};`.

In any case, when using `std::thread`, you are passing it a *reference* to `pipeF`. My guess is that `pipeF` is going out of scope and being destroyed before the thread has a chance to call its `operator()`. If a `std::thread` callback throws an uncaught exception (such as by accessing data members of an invalid `PipeFunctor` object), `std::terminate()` gets called, which in turn calls `std::abort()` by default.

Comment: Thanks for the perspective Remy. Are you saying that PipeFunctor pipeF() is not "direct initialization" of a pipeF object of the PipeFunctor class, using its default constructor?

Comment: The abort() error is being thrown when the ConnectNamedPipe() function is being called, which is called from a ConnectClient() method, which is called from the operator() overloaded method, which means the operator() method is indeed being called. Sorry if that wasn't clear enough. I do agree, it may have something to do with std::thread (perhaps its default parameters) and will investigate accordingly..

Comment: @AndikanOtung that is what I'm saying, yes. There is an ambiguity in the language known as "Most Vexing Parse". If something *looks* like a function declaration, it is treated as a function declaration, even if that is not what you intended it to be.

Comment: @AndikanOtung As for `abort()`, there is no way that `ConnectNamedPipe()` itself can call `abort()`, but an uncaught exception thrown in the context of a `std::thread` can. Your `operator()` is likely being called on an invalid `pipeF` object, causing an Access Violation. Compare the operator's `this` pointer to `pipeF`, and log the creation and destruction of `pipeF`. You are likely to see `pipeF` destroyed before the operator is called on it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about "most vexing parse". My actual code provides inputs to the variable initialization, but, for simplicity, I left it out of the example code provided (blissfully unaware of this phenomenon!).

Answer (score 0):

The error was resolved by changing the line:

```
std::thread (std::ref(pipeF));
```

to:

```
std::thread  name_of_thread (std::ref(pipeF));
```

As @Remy-Lebeau mentions, this is likely because the thread was "going out of scope" thus causing std::thread to throw an uncaught exception and subsequently causing std::abort() to be called.